# Reconhecer aria-selected="false" com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Como faço um jQuery que reconheça se `aria-selected="false"` e se true trocar o background da div "seta-btn-sub" para outra imagem (img de seta). Isso é parte de um acordion e quero trocar a img da seta quando estiver aberta a parte (`<div id="outraDiv">`), o 'area selected' aparece dentro do h3.

```
<h3>
  <a>Banho</a>
  <div class="seta-btn-sub"></div>
</h3>
<div id="outraDiv"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Condicionadores</a><span></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">sabonetes</a><span></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">shampoos</a><span></span></li>
    <li><a href="#">outros</a><span></span></li>    
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Fiz algo assim até agora, mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar como desejo

```
<script>
    if($("#aria-selected").val() == true){
        $(".seta-btn-sub").css("background-image","url(images/seta-blue.png);");
    }
    else if($("#aria-selected").val() == false){
        $(".seta-btn-sub").css("background-image","url(images/seta-padrao-azul.png);");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Até onde eu entendo o `aria-selected` deve ser definido por uma implementação específica, não é algo automático do HTML ou do navegador. Tem algum plugin específico que você está usando?

Comment: Sim, estou usando "acoordion" (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) que insere dentro do h3 o condição (aria-selected="true") quando abro a UL desejada, o que desejo é alterar a img da seta (background da div seta-btn-sub) que fica para o lado, para uma outra seta. Resumindo, ou seja, quando for (aria-selected="true") alterar o background da div "seta-btn-sub"para outro background-image. Obrigado

Comment: @CRAJ Lembre que, caso você queira dizer mais coisas sobre o seu problema (como o exemplo de código que você postou) não é necessário criar uma nova resposta. Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar as informações necessárias. Bem vindo ao SOPT :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `.accordion()` tem dois eventos chamados `beforeActivate` e `create` utilizei os dois eventos para manipular o cabeçalho e para remover os icones utilizei o *option* `icons`.

No `beforeActive` os cabeçalhos são `ui.newHeader` para o elemento que acabou de ser ativado e `ui.oldHeader` para o elemento que acabou de ser desativado.

No `create` o cabeçalho é o `ui.header` que retornará o elemento ativo do cabeçalho assim que o `.accordion()` for criado.

O resultado do código foi esse:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        icons: null,
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#" + ui.newHeader.attr("id")).children(".seta-btn-sub").toggleClass("active");
            $("#" + ui.oldHeader.attr("id")).children(".seta-btn-sub").toggleClass("active");
        },
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#" + ui.header.attr("id")).children(".seta-btn-sub").toggleClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Para fazer os teste com background utilizei este [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
.seta-btn-sub {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.seta-btn-sub.active{
    background: #00FF00;
}
```

Dessa forma você vai poder inserir este código e colocar o [css](/questions/tagged/css) para exibir o que precisar.

Comment: Olhando essa resposta acho que finalmente entendi a pergunta!

Comment: esse (header) e esse (activeHeader) são pre determinados ou são variáveis?

Comment: eles fazem parte do jSon de configuração do `.accordion()` você pode ver exatamente como fica aqui http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons

Comment: Mas basta inserir no JS o código e criar as classes com as imgs que quero? Por que fiz isso mas não aconteceu nada...estão iguais a antes

Comment: Você quer colocar imagens personalizadas no lugar dos icones do [tag:jQuery-ui]?

Comment: Sim, são 2 imagens diferentes, parecidas, porem diferentes..

Comment: OK, mas essas imagens são suas e não são os icones do [tag:jquery-ui]  é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, são 2 imagens que desenvolvi.

Comment: Ok, em breve edito minha resposta para uma que caiba melhor à sua necessidade.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, fico no aguardo pois até o momento não achei nada eficaz..

Comment: Espero que agora tenha ficado da forma que vocêm precisa

Comment: Muito Obrigado Erlon, realmente ficou como eu pensava, vou pegar essa estrutura e estudar mais. Novamente Obrigado!!

Comment: Se puder marcar como certo eu agradeço :D